# Vue cant find api with nuxt3

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3

Why does vue returns [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H434V.png) when i try to call my api?
I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5joQP.png) router setup and my api code is this:

```
import { useQuery } from "h3";
import * as Pages from "~/assets/json/sites.json";

export default async (req, res) => {
  const query = await useQuery(req);
  return Pages.default.find((e) => {
    e.psw == query.psw;
  });
};
```

Edit: I tried refreshing the lockfile but it didn't help. The path /api/getHref/index.js is empty too...

nvm got it to working using this code:

```
import { useQuery } from "h3";
import fs from "fs";
var Pages = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("assets/json/sites.json", "utf8"));

export default async (req, res) => {
  const query = await useQuery(req);
  var result = Pages.find((e) => {
    return e.psw == query.psw;
  });
  if(result == undefined) return ""
  return JSON.stringify(result.href);
};
```